# Difference between @Inject and @AssistedInjected?

Tags: guice, guice-3

The page regarding [assisted injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject) explains how assisted injection can be done by annotating some parameters in the constructor with `@Assisted` but it does not explain what the `@AssistedInject` annotation is for and how it differs from `@Inject`. Is that annotation somehow related? What are the differences?

Answer (score 4):

`@Inject` and `@AssistedInject` both are used to annotate constructors which are supposed to be invoked using the injector of the Guice module being used.

The only difference is, `@Inject` is used when the factory has only one method to create the type, while `@AssistedInject` is used when the factory has multiple such methods corresponding to multiple constructors for the type. It is more of a detail to assist Guice in distinguishing the two cases.

Answer (score 2):

From http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/AssistedInject.html

> When used in tandem with FactoryModuleBuilder, constructors annotated
>   with @AssistedInject indicate that multiple constructors can be
>   injected, each with different parameters. AssistedInject annotations
>   should not be mixed with @Inject annotations. The assisted parameters
>   must exactly match one corresponding factory method within the factory
>   interface, but the parameters do not need to be in the same order.
>   Constructors annotated with AssistedInject are created by Guice and
>   receive all the benefits (such as AOP).
>
> Obsolete Usage: When used in tandem with FactoryProvider, constructors
>   annotated with @AssistedInject trigger a "backwards compatibility
>   mode". The assisted parameters must exactly match one corresponding
>   factory method within the factory interface and all must be in the
>   same order as listed in the factory. In this backwards compatable
>   mode, constructors annotated with AssistedInject are not created by
>   Guice and thus receive none of the benefits.
>
> Constructor parameters must be either supplied by the factory
>   interface and marked with @Assisted, or they must be injectable.